# UnityWebRequest how to print all Request headers

Tags: c#, http, unity-game-engine, header, request

Is there a way to print all the request headers from the UnityWebRequest API? 
(I'm especially interested in the one automatically added "x-unity-version" and "user-agent")

Also, where are these headers are stored in the code?

Comment: *"Where does these headers are added in the code?"* I think you should rephrase this because I don't understand that. Also, the header you want to print, is it the header that `UnityWebRequest` is sending or the one that it is receiving from the server?

Comment: I mentioned 'request headers',  that should be self explanatory.. But in case... Those are the one sent to server. By my second question I meant where are they stored? Which object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> where are these headers are stored in the code?

They are automatically added to a variable on the native side (C++). As of *Unity 5.6.03f* release, you cannot access these headers that are automatically added to the `UnityWebRequest` API with the official API. You can't even use reflection to do this since it only has a write but no read function.

> Is there a way to print all the request headers from the UnityWebRequest API?

**Yes**, but that's tricky since you can't do this with the official API or with reflection.

You have to create a local server with `HttpListener` in another `Thread`, connect to it with `UnityWebRequest` then retrieve all the headers from the `HttpListenerRequest` of the `HttpListener` API and store them in a `List`.You can then close the `HttpListener` server.

```
volatile bool serverIsReady = false;
//Holds List of all the headers from received from UnityWebRequest request
List<HeaderInfo> headers = new List<HeaderInfo>();

void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(getUnityWebRequestHeaders());
}

IEnumerator getUnityWebRequestHeaders()
{
    //Start Http Server
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(RunInNewThread), new string[] { "http://*:8080/" });

    //Wait for server to actually start
    while (!serverIsReady)
        yield return null;

    Debug.LogWarning("Server is ready");

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.2f);


    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post("http://localhost:8080", "");
    yield return www.Send();

    //Check if connections was successfull
    if (!www.isError && www.downloadHandler.text.Contains("SUCCESS"))
    {
        Debug.LogWarning("Connection was successfull");
    }

    //Show all the headers from UnityWebRequest
    for (int i = 0; i < headers.Count; i++)
    {
        Debug.Log("KEY: " + headers[i].header + "    -    VALUE: " + headers[i].value);
    }
}

private void RunInNewThread(object a)
{
    //Cast parameter back to string array
    string[] serverPrefix = (string[])a;
    //Start server with the provided parameter
    SimpleListenerExample(serverPrefix);
}

//Creates a http server
public void SimpleListenerExample(string[] prefixes)
{
    serverIsReady = false;

    if (!HttpListener.IsSupported)
    {
        Debug.LogWarning("Windows XP SP2 or Server 2003 is required to use the HttpListener class.");
        return;
    }
    //URI prefixes are required,
    //for example "http://contoso.com:8080/index/".
    if (prefixes == null || prefixes.Length == 0)
        throw new ArgumentException("prefixes");

    //Create a listener.
    HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
    //Add the prefixes.
    foreach (string s in prefixes)
    {
        listener.Prefixes.Add(s);
    }
    listener.Start();
    Debug.LogWarning("Listening...");

    serverIsReady = true;

    //Note: The GetContext method blocks while waiting for a request. 
    HttpListenerContext context = listener.GetContext();
    HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;
    //Obtain a response object.
    HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;
    //Construct a response.
    string responseString = "<HTML><BODY>SUCCESS</BODY></HTML>";
    byte[] buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseString);
    //Get a response stream and write the response to it.
    response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
    System.IO.Stream output = response.OutputStream;
    output.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

    //Get all the headers sent from UnityWebRequest and add them to the List
    addHeaders(request);

    //You must close the output stream.
    output.Close();
    listener.Stop();
}

//Get all the headers sent from UnityWebRequest
void addHeaders(HttpListenerRequest request)
{
    System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection receivedHeaders = request.Headers;
    for (int i = 0; i < receivedHeaders.Count; i++)
    {
        string key = receivedHeaders.GetKey(i);
        string value = receivedHeaders.Get(i);
        headers.Add(new HeaderInfo(key, value));
    }
}

//Hold header and value
public class HeaderInfo
{
    public string header;
    public string value;

    public HeaderInfo(string header, string value)
    {
        this.header = header;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

**Output** with *Unity 5.6.03f*:

> KEY: Host    -    VALUE: localhost:8080
>
> KEY: User-Agent    -    VALUE: UnityPlayer/5.6.0f3
>   (UnityWebRequest/1.0, libcurl/7.51.0-DEV)
>
> KEY: Accept    -    VALUE: */*
>
> KEY: Accept-Encoding    -    VALUE: identity
>
> KEY: Content-Type    -    VALUE: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
> KEY: X-Unity-Version    -    VALUE: 5.6.0f3
>
> KEY: Content-Length    -    VALUE: 0